# Is there any way to do email confirmation for Firebase user creation and/or password reset?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Question says it all. In Firebase, how do I confirm email when a user creates an account, or, for that matter, do password reset via email.

I could ask more broadly: is there any way to send emails out from Firebase? E.g. notifications, etc. This isn't the kind of thing you would usually do client-side.

Comment: Starting today its one of built-in Firebase features: http://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/05/firebase-expands-to-become-unified-app-platform.html :)

Comment: Check the answer below to see how to do the email verification in 2016

Comment: To the more general question of 'emails from Firebase' - yes there is now. :) There's a link to the details in my answer below...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This would need to be done outside of firebase. I store users at /users/ and keep a status on them (PENDING, ACTIVE, DELETED). I have a small service that monitors users of a PENDING status and sends out a confirmation email.  Which has a link to a webservice I've created to update the user status to ACTIVE.

Comment: So, nice as Firebase is, I still need a server process watching it.

Comment: Same thing for payment processing, e.g. using Stripe. I can request it from the browser, get the token, hand it to Firebase (or backendless, or whatever you like), but to actually process the payment and know it went through, I need some external server process.

Comment: How does your service monitor /users/ status? Is it pinging it every few minutes/seconds? Is it a push service?

Comment: im using the firebase java api, to subscribe to any status value changes on a user.

Comment: That kind of async stuff I tend to like better in nodejs, but same idea. So you just subscribe, and it calls the callback? Works for me.

Comment: A bit of a strange workflow though: 1) user registers via Firebase API, which puts the "new user" flag in place; 2) Some other server picks up on the change, sends out the email; 3) the user confirms the email. Also, the security model is a bit odd, since you need to make sure that the new user creation is not created without the "NEW" or "UNCONFIRMED" flag. Definitely different way of thinking.... reminds of me of couchapps and similar.

Comment: @deitch you'll find that the "server process you need watching it" is reduced to a simple script (another consumer with higher privileges), something you could install at Heroku, for instance, instead of a server stack involving log rotations, disk management, scalability, databases, security, patches, networking, servers, and firewalls. So it's still a pretty nice deal!

Comment: Yeah, I see that. I definitely get the BaaS concept, having repeated building infra and then common services so many times. Still, there are a few really common services - payment like Stripe and email sending - that would be nice to eliminate the last of them.

Comment: A more elegant solution would be for Firebase to provide WebHooks. This way you wouldn't need an intermediate process/server to do the watching.

Comment: Firebase can now send out customized password reset emails: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html#section-reset-email.

Comment: Check the answer below to learn how to do the email verification in 2016

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. It is now possible to send emails direct from Firebase.

Answer (score 48):

**Update**

Note that this was never a very secure way of handling email verification, and since Firebase now supports email verification, it should probably be used instead.

**Original answer**

I solved the email verification using the password reset feature.

On account creation I give the user a temporary (randomly generated) password. I then trigger a password reset which will send an email to the user with a link. The link will allow the user to set a new password.

To generate a random password you can use code similar to this:

```
function () {
  var possibleChars = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!?_-'];
  var password = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < 16; i += 1) {
    password += possibleChars[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleChars.length)];
  }
  return password;
}
```

Note that this is happening on the client, so a malicious user could tamper with your logic.

Comment: +1 for a very innovative solution! Thanks. Is there any way for the user's verified email to be accessed from within security rules? auth.email does not appear to available with simple login auth payload.

Comment: Just beware this is not safe. The random password is generated on the client side which means the user can modify or sniff the temporary password and login with that (without verifying via email)

Comment: Is the linked solution possible on android? I see how I could parse out the temporary token, but how would I use it to verify it was from the email the user is about to re-enter?

Comment: As long as Firebase allows clients to create an account with an unchecked email (regardless of which password is assigned), it is unsafe anyway. So it is an acceptable tradeoff. Nice solution.

Comment: You don't need to use the password reset anymore. See answer below

Comment: Something wonky seems to be going on with your site - I've edited the link to use a Wayback machine link. Please feel free to rollback the edit or otherwise restore the link if you can.

Comment: Hi @andreasmcd - how do I achieve what I need with the new Firebase? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729486/firebase-email-verification-workflow

Answer (score 23):

[Engineer at Firebase - Update 2014-01-27]

Firebase Simple Login now supports password resets for email / password authentication.

Each of the Simple Login client libraries has been given a new method for generating password reset emails for the specified email address - `sendPasswordResetEmail()` on the Web and Android, and `sendPasswordResetForEmail()` on iOS.

This e-mail will contain a temporary token that the user may use to log into their account and update their credentials. This token will expire after 24 hours or when the user changes their password, whichever occurs first.

Also note that Firebase Simple Login enables full configuration of the email template as well as the sending address (including whitelabel email from your domain for paid accounts).

To get access to this feature, you'll need to update your client library to a version of `v1.2.0` or greater. To grab the latest version, check out https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html.

Also, check out https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html for the latest Firebase Simple Login - Web Client docs.

Comment: How would I detect if the user is using a temporary password or a permanent one? This is important because I want to redirect users using temporary passwords to a form where they can set a permanent one.

Comment: @finishingmove We're working on adding a way to detect that case, but I'd be interested in getting your feedback on how to best implement that for you.

Comment: Well, for now, I'm storing user info in a collection called `users`, and I was thinking of storing a boolean that would indicate this status temporarily on the user objects in that collection. It would be nice though, if this were automatically done by Firebase, and accessible on the $firebaseSimpleLogin.user (in case of angularFire) object. Thoughts?

Comment: @finishingmove Thanks for the feedback - I'll give that some thought and update this item when we move on the task.

Comment: I created an issue on angularFire here https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/275

Comment: How do I solve this in the new Firebase @RobDiMarco? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729486/firebase-email-verification-workflow

Answer (score 9):

As at 2016 July, you might not have to use the reset link etc. Just use the [`sendEmailVerification()` and `applyActionCode`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendEmailVerification) functions:

In short, below is basically how you'll approach this, in AngularJS:

```
// thecontroller.js
$scope.sendVerifyEmail = function() {
    console.log('Email sent, whaaaaam!');
    currentAuth.sendEmailVerification();
  }

// where currentAuth came from something like this:
// routerconfig

....
templateUrl: 'bla.html',
resolve: {
    currentAuth:['Auth', function(Auth) {
      return Auth.$requireSignIn() // this throws an AUTH_REQUIRED broadcast
    }]
  }
...

// intercept the broadcast like so if you want:

....

$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
      if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
        $state.go('login', { toWhere: toState });
       }
    });
....

// So user receives the email. How do you process the `oobCode` that returns?
// You may do something like this:

// catch the url with its mode and oobCode
.state('emailVerify', {
  url: '/verify-email?mode&oobCode',
  templateUrl: 'auth/verify-email.html',
  controller: 'emailVerifyController',
  resolve: {
    currentAuth:['Auth', function(Auth) {
      return Auth.$requireSignIn()
    }]
  }
})

// Then digest like so where each term is what they sound like:

.controller('emailVerifyController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'currentAuth', 'DatabaseRef',
  function($scope, $stateParams, currentAuth, DatabaseRef) {
    console.log(currentAuth);
    $scope.doVerify = function() {
      firebase.auth()
        .applyActionCode($stateParams.oobCode)
        .then(function(data) {
          // change emailVerified for logged in User
          console.log('Verification happened');
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          $scope.error = error.message;
          console.log(error.message, error.reason)
        })
    };
  }
])
```

And ooh, with the above approach, I do not think there's any need keeping the verification of your user's email in your user data area. The `applyActionCode` changes the `emailVerified` to `true` from `false`.

Email verification is important when users sign in with the local account. However, for many social authentications, the incoming `emailVerified` will be `true` already.

Explained more in the article [Email Verification with Firebase 3.0 SDK](https://blog.khophi.co/email-verification-firebase-3-0-sdk/)

Comment: great answer - how would I do this a) without Angular and b) just adding users to my database, and then using Zapier perhaps to trigger a confirmation link from Sendgrid, and then when the link in the email is clicked then add the users to authenticated users data section? Or how can I handle everything using Firebase? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729486/firebase-email-verification-workflow

Answer (score 7):

What I did to work around this was use Zapier which has a built in API for firebase. It checks a location for added child elements. Then it takes the mail address and a verification url from the data of new nodes and sends them forwards. The url points back to my angular app, which sets the user email as verified.

As I host my app files in firebase, I don't need have to take care of any servers or processes doing polling in the background.

There is a delay, but as I don't block users before verifying mails it's ok. Zapier has a free tier and since I don't have much traffic it's a decent workaround for time being.

Comment: thanks. I will look at this when I have a chance. As of now, my projects no longer look at Firebase, but the next one that can, I will.

Comment: Timo, thanks for the nice idea but i cannot understand how do you generate a verification url and store it in firebase. Can you please give a more detailed example of verification flow with Zapier?

Answer (score 2):

The new Firebase SDK v3 appears to support email address verification, see [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/your_project/authentication/emails) (put your own project id in the link) but it doesn't appear to be documented yet.

I have asked the question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142317/how-to-use-firebase-email-address-verification)

See @SamQuayle's answer there with [this link to the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendEmailVerification).

Comment: When will the email verification Api be available for Android? The official documentation still authenticates without verification.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by various others Firebase does now support account related emails but even better, as of 10 days ago or so it also supports sending any kind of email via Firebase Functions. Lots of details in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and example code [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users).

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to check the email verification after creating new account.

```
let firAuth = FIRAuth.auth()
firAuth?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
    if let loggedUser = user {

        if loggedUser.emailVerified == false {

            loggedUser.sendEmailVerificationWithCompletion({ (error) in

                print("error:\(error)")
            })
        }
        else {

            print(loggedUser.email)
        }
    } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        print("No user is signed in.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I used MandrillApp. You can create an API key that only allows sending of a template. This way even thought your key is exposed it can't really be abused unless someone wants to fire off tonnes of welcome emails for you.

That was a hack to get myself off the ground. I'm now enabling CORS from a EC2 that uses the token to verify that the user exists before extending them a welcome via SES.