# New user email verification

Tags: firebase

I am trying to implement email user verification when creating new users with 'createUSer'.

Does FireBase have any support for that ? do I need third party code/hosting ?

Comment: This still sounds correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723195/is-there-any-way-to-do-email-confirmation-for-firebase-user-creation-and-or-pass

Comment: yeah I saw that but the solutions given there seem very hackish for two reasons: First they use the reset password email mechanism and so make it impossible to distinguish between a password reset and an actual registration, two distinctly different operarions. Second they rely on the _client_ generating a random 'temp' password which is not secure. It's been two years since sendPasswordResetEmail() .. does no better, more standard way for email verification exist ?

Comment: I'll move the discussion to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723195/is-there-any-way-to-do-email-confirmation-for-firebase-user-creation-and-or-pass

Comment: Frank I hope you can comment there - the issue is not resolved

Comment: The answers there are still the ways that I know of to do something akin to email verification with Firebase. If neither Zapier, nor a custom mail sending process, nor password reset emails suit your needs, you'll have to come up with something else yourself.

Comment: ok I hope the FB team will get to implement this important feature in a proper way. I moved the discussion to https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/firebase-talk/FwCbDjQchBY

Comment: I came up with this solution: https://github.com/kofifus/FirebaseEmailVerification