# How to send Firebase email confirmation on signup?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So, I have enabled email/password in the dev console and everything is working fine. Except that I should be getting a confirmation email to the email I inputted, but I'm not getting it. I thought it does it automatically, but apparently it doesn't.

---

**Method for signup:**

```
public void signUp(View v) {
    String email = emailET.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordET.getText().toString();
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d("AD", "createUserWithEmail: " + task.isSuccessful() + task.getException());
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        createDialogSignUpError(
                                getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.signUpFailedET),
                                getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.signUpFailedEM),
                                getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(android.R.string.ok));
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Registration Successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

It should be sending, but sadly it's not. I've read somewhere on SO that you need to add a method or something to send the email, and it's missing in the docs, but that wasn't Java.

---

**Edit**

According to [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714), it is only supported in iOS and web. Which is pretty surprising, since after all, *android* IS Google, and Google is Firebase. So is it possible even with creating a custom sent email?

---

**Edit 2:** To be more clear, does Android have an **Email** sender like C#. That would be the best solution if there isn't an API for this.

Comment: I guess you are right, reading the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) this is only available in ios and swift. There is also some discussions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723195/is-there-any-way-to-do-email-confirmation-for-firebase-user-creation-and-or-pass) if you want to look to some workarounds.

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate, if you didn't read, I said that I've seen questions like that and mine is completely different.

Comment: Have you read this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723195/is-there-any-way-to-do-email-confirmation-for-firebase-user-creation-and-or-pass

Comment: Email address verification is currently an experimental feature on iOS and Web.

Comment: @SundayGAkinsete which is exactly what I mentioned in my post...

Answer (score 2):

Now according to the [updated firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email)

Here is how to send a verification mail to the user that in your case is after creating the account and letting the user to log-in then send him/her a notification that he have to verify the account and then the next login is blocked until he/she didn't verify (I think this is better than making the user is forced to open his email first)

> Send a user a verification email
>
> You can send an address verification email to a user with the
>   sendEmailVerification method. For example:
>
> ```
> FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
>
> user.sendEmailVerification()
>         .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
>             @Override
>             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
>                 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
>                     Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
>                 }
>             }
>         });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can now plug any Firebase gaps in email coverage by rolling your own email sender using Firebase Cloud Functions. There's an example [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users). Of course this means more work than just configuring like the built-in options but at least means we can do whatever we need to do. :)