# Firebase Email verification not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links, email-verification

I am looking for help to the same question as in
[Firebase Email verification not working with ActionCodeSetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178015/firebase-email-verification-not-working-with-actioncodesetting)

The answer is unfortunately incomplete (to me), and I cannot comment on the original answer as I'm new to SO.

What I'd like to know is whether or not it is required to implement the custom email handler (as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) on an external host (as in the guide), or if this can be done on iOS client itself?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do that client side (on the iOS device) by [passing state in the email action](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/passing-state-in-email-actions).

Comment: thank you.  I was away on another project. Do you have sample code? 
 Firebase documentation is not clear at all on how to actually do this.